# deleting object duplicates from list considering a certain field

Tags: java, list

I've a list of  objects with different cdOption, cdVersion and cdDescription.

Some of these have the same cdOption but different cdVersion, and I need to get the list of the objects with a different cdOption, so I'm trying to remove the duplicate considering only the cdOption field.

So far I've got this:

```
List<Option> noDuplicateOptions = new ArrayList<Option>();
List<Option> options = resp.get(RESULT);

for (Option option : options) {
    for (Option noDuplicateOption : noDuplicateOptions) {
        if (option.getCdOption().equals(noDuplicateOption.getCdOption())) {
        noDuplicateOptions.add(option);
    }
}
}

return noDuplicateOptions;
```

but is there a faster and optimized way to do this?

Edit: the solution I've used is overriding the equals method in Option like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
return obj instanceof Option && ((Option)obj).getCdOption() == cdOption;
}
```

then I can do this:

```
List<Option> options = resp.get(RESULT);

Map<String, Option> map = new HashMap<String, Option>();
for (Option option : options) {
    map.put(option.getCdOption(), option);
}
options.clear();
options.addAll(map.values());

return options;
```

Comment: "but is there a faster and optimized way to do this?" have you profiled your application and seen an actual performance degredation because of this code? If not, there's no need to optimize. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HashMap. In a loop through all options, check to see if an option is in the HashMap. If it isn't, add it to the HashMap and a new array, if it is, do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Program execution never reaches inside this loop as there are no elements in `noDuplicateOptions`:

```
for (Option noDuplicateOption : noDuplicateOptions) {
    // ...
}
```

I am almost certain your code returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set` to remove duplicate `cdOption`. You need to add `Comparator` with the basis of `cdOption`, like:

```
 Set<Option> set=new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Option>() {

        @Override
        public int compare( Option o1, Option o2) {
            return o1.getCdOption().compareTo(o2.getCdOption());
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit ill posed. You say "I am trying to get *the* list of objects with different cdOption. However, since you have duplicates (with respect to cdVersion) you can get only *a* list of representant or a list of the cdOptions (instead of *the* list of *object*).

This might be subtle. But there is no "the" in this list of objects. There are many possible such lists.

Since you are asking for a faster way: Often a good way to handle such cases is to do this upon construction of the List, i.e. you maintain two Lists. One with all options, one with *a* subset of options with unique cdOptions.... (eg. write your own extension of List).